# Duplex printing issue - multiple copies print back-to-back rather than separately

Tags: printer, duplex

I have a Dell H625cdw printer and currently have 2 up and doubled sided printing enabled.

**The issue** - When we try and print 2 copies of a 5 page document, the second copy will start on the back of the third physical page (i.e. on the back of *page number* 5).

**Question** - How do I set the second copy to start on a fresh sheet of paper?

Comment: Does this problem happen regardless of the software you're using? For example, if it's a MS Word document, does the same thing happen if you save it as a PDF and then print it from Adobe Reader?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: As a workaround, *if* you can identify that a print job has an odd number of pages, you can put a job in the print queue right behind it with a document  which only contains a formfeed (Ctrl+L or 0xC). Or you can append it to the end of the source of the print job (if it's a file or a data stream you have access to.) If you create and save a file like this in advance, you can just use when you need it. The original problem sounds like a bug in your printing software or in the printer firmware.